# how to convert android.util.Base64.encodeToString to C#

Tags: c#, android

```
import android.util.Base64; 

public static String Base64(String str) {
    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, 0);

    return base64;
}
```

it is a android method to convert base64

```
public string Base64(string str)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);        
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

    return base64;
}
```

it is c# method

but both output are different

what can i do for same output??

Comment: Well what is the output you are getting??

Comment: And for what input

Comment: in android input is 50 and output is NTA\u003d\n And in C# input is same but output is NTA=

Comment: public static String Base64(String str) {
        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        try {
            data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, 0);
        System.out.println("Encoding String :" + base64);
        return base64;
    }

Comment: thank you problem solved, in android retrofit replace = to \u003d\n